# dojo popup is closing automatically

Tags: java, jsp, dojo, jsp-tags

I have a JSP file with the following content

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="portlet" uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="tag" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>

<portlet:defineObjects />


<portlet:actionURL var="action" />

<script>
dojo.require("dojo.parser");
dojo.require("dijit.TitlePane");  
dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
dojo.require("dijit.Tree");
dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");
dojo.require("dijit.Tooltip");

dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Form");
dojo.require("dojox.validate");
dojo.require("dojox.validate.web");
dojo.require("dojox.validate.us");
dojo.require("dijit.form.DropDownButton");
dojo.require("dijit.TooltipDialog");
</script>

<form:form name="SubmitForm" action="${action}"> 

<input style="display:block;" id="btnUploadConfirm" class="actionBtn" type="submit" value="Upload" style="float: right;" name="" onclick="dijit.byId('dialogUpload').show();"  /> 

<div dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="b2" position="above"> Upload </div>



</form:form>

 <div id="dialogUpload" class="confirmationPopupSE popupWidth" dojoType="dijit.Dialog" title="Upload Document" >
 <form method="post" action="<portlet:actionURL/>" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validate();"> 
 <input type="file" name="file" id="uploadFile" /> <br />
 <div id="errorUpload" class="errorMsg"></div>

 <br />
 <div class="">
 <input id="btnUploadConfirm" class="tableButton" type="submit" value="Upload" name="" onclick="setAction2('upload');" />
 <input id="btnUploadCancel" class="tableButton" type="button" value="Cancel"
  onclick="document.getElementById('errorUpload').innerHTML = '';document.getElementById('errorUpload').style.display='none';dijit.byId('dialogUpload').hide();" />
 </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

If i run with above jsp file, and click the upload button, the popup comes, but it closes instantly.

But if i run the above code WITHOUT the outer  form:form  tag, the popup works properly as expected and doesnt close by itself.. what is the problem with this?

Comment: Q: *What* is the difference between the working case the the failing case?

Comment: working case:the popup should not close automatically and instantly when i click the  button.
   Failing case:the popup is getting closed automatically and instantly when i click the  button

Comment: question edited now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try stopping the propagation of the click event:

```
 <input id="btnUploadConfirm" [snip] onclick="setAction2('upload');return false;" />
```

Or maybe just remove `type="submit"` from btnUploadConfirm